# Switching a slider from using a button to just the whole image as a link

Tags: html, smarty

I'm trying to switch a promo slider from using a "view" button with the link to just using the whole image as the link instead of the button.  I believe I've found the controlling block of code, but I'm not sure what exactly to edit.

```
<div id="blocksliderpluspromo">
<div id="promo_show">
    <div class="promoborder">
        <div id="camera_wrap">
            {foreach from=$slides.$lang_iso item=image name=singleimage}                
            {if $image["lang_iso"] == $lang_iso and $image["lang_iso"]|@count != 0}              
                <div data-src="{$minicSlider.path.images}{$image.image}" {if $minicSlider.options.thumbnail == 1}data-thumb="{$minicSlider.path.thumbs}{$image.image}"{/if} data-video="hide">
                    {if $image.caption != ''}
                        <div class="camera_caption">{$image.caption}</div>                                    
                    {/if}
                    <div class="button_container item_{$smarty.foreach.singleimage.index}">
                        {if $image.url != ''}
                        <a href="{$image.url}" class="button_small" {if $image.target == 1}target="_blank"{/if}>
                            <span>{l s='View' mod='promominicslider'}</span>
                        </a>
                        {/if}
                    </div>                
                </div>
                {/if}                                    
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you so much!

Comment: @chris yes it's smarty.  I got it too work! Thanks guys! Just made the link into a new class and deleted the button span.

Comment: @NickKassatly Why don't you post your solution as an answer? That way, if someone comes across this in the future your question could save them time. Nothing worse than looking for answers, finding a guy with the exact same question, and he just says, "I figured it out." -- AHHHHH!! HOW! :D